# Where are the Filters?

Tags: drivers, printing

My Samsung multifunction printer has been working fine, then without warning it stopped. I can switch to Windows 10 and it works fine. I have a disk image of my computer from a few days before the printer quit. If I knew what directory(s) the printer installation files were located, I could copy those directories and all should be well without losing documents that are located elsewhere on my computer. Since the printer stopped working, I have deleted it, and thought I could reinstall it. However, now I can only find Windows drivers on the Samsung sight. Any help out there?

Comment: samsung printer driver can be optained with these directions http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll save the link for the next time. I used my week-old disk image to overwrite my hard drive this morning to get my printer going again. I remembered some of my changed files, but not all, but I can live without that data.